# Rabbit Mq java client parallel consumption

Tags: java, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I want to process messages from a rabbitMq queue in parallel. The queue is configured to be autoAck =false. I am using the camel-rabbitMQ support for [camel endpoints](http://camel.apache.org/rabbitmq.html), which has support for a threadPoolSize parameter, but this does not have the desired effect. Messages are still processed serially off the queue, even when threadpoolsize=20.

From debugging through the code I can see that the threadpoolsize parameter is used to create an ExecutorService that is used to pass to the rabbit connectionfactory as described [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#advanced-connection). This all looks good until you get into the rabbit `ConsumerWorkService`. Here messages are processed in block of max size 16 messages. Each message in a block is processed serially and then if there is more work to do the executor service is invokes with the next block. A code snippet of this is below. From this use of the executor service I can't see how the messages can be processed in parallel. The executorservice only ever has one piece of work to perform at a time.

What am I Missing?

```
private final class WorkPoolRunnable implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            int size = MAX_RUNNABLE_BLOCK_SIZE;
            List<Runnable> block = new ArrayList<Runnable>(size);
            try {
                Channel key = ConsumerWorkService.this.workPool.nextWorkBlock(block, size);
                if (key == null) return; // nothing ready to run
                try {
                    for (Runnable runnable : block) {
                        runnable.run();
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (ConsumerWorkService.this.workPool.finishWorkBlock(key)) {
                        ConsumerWorkService.this.executor.execute(new WorkPoolRunnable());
                    }
                }
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you configure ConsumerWorkService to use a different block size?

Comment: Hi Claus, I've been making some changes to the Camel-rabbitmq component via github as Fergus Nelson. I have made changes the RabbitMqConsumer to set up a channel for each concurant consumer required. I will create a Jira + pull request when I have tested everything.

Comment: @mR_fr0g, as I understand, you've fixed the issue by creating multiple channels in Camel-RabbitMQ component. Could you provide the link to your Jira ticket, pull request and specify in which Camel version the fix is present?

Answer (score 8):

RabbitMQ's documentation is not very clear about this but, even though the `ConsumerWorkService` is using a thread pool, this pool doesn't seem to be used in a way to process messages in parallel:

> Each Channel has its own dispatch thread. For the most common use case of one Consumer per Channel, this means Consumers do not hold up other Consumers. If you have multiple Consumers per Channel be aware that a long-running Consumer may hold up dispatch of callbacks to other Consumers on that Channel.

(http://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html)

This documentation suggests using one `Channel` per thread and, in fact, if you simply create as many `Channel`s as the required level of concurrency, messages will be dispatched between the consumers linked to these channels.

I've tested with 2 channels and consumers: when 2 messages are in the queue, each consumer only picks one message at a time. The blocks of 16 messages you mentioned don't seem to interfere, which is a good thing.

As a matter of fact, Spring AMQP also creates as several channels to process messages concurrently. This is done by:

- setting `SimpleMessageListenerContainer.setConcurrentConsumers(...)`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.6.RELEASE/api/
- and setting `CachingConnectionFactory.setChannelCacheSize(...)` accordingly: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.6.RELEASE/api/

I've also tested this to be working as expected.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a single `Channel` instance, it's going to invoke its registered consumers serially as you correctly found out by examining `ConsumerWorkService`. There are 2 ways to overcome that:

1. Use multiple channels instead of one.
2. Use single channel but implement consumers in a special way. They should just pick incoming message from queue and put it as a task into an internal thread pool.

You can find more details in [this post](https://wheleph.gitlab.io/posts/2015-09-06-rabbitmq-async-consumption/).